# Cursor moving too fast in QEMU when using touchpad

Tags: linux, touchpad, qemu

I am running Windows inside QEMU on a Linux host. QEMU is running X with libinput. When I use the touchpad to control the mouse inside the guest, the pointer moves very rapidly and stutters. This problem does not occur when using an external mouse.

I have tried setting `SDL_VIDEO_X11_DGAMOUSE=0`, but that did not have any effect. Passing `-usbdevice tablet` helps, but I want QEMU to capture mouse input.

Has anyone else found a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same issue.

The way it was solved was simply by:

- opening the `Control Panel` in the Windows 7 guest,
- open the `Mouse settings`
- select the `Pointer Options` tab
- finally in the `Select a pointer speed` section

  - slide it **left** to your needs
    (picture here: http://dev.garment.fr/images/pointer-speed.png)

Comment: Wouldn't this also affect pointer speed when using an external mouse, though?